# How to specify the equivalent of ppn (on PBS) in SGE queuing system?

Tags: queue, task, pbs, sungridengine

Is there a way to specify the `ppn` ( or equivalent ) in `SGE` ? i don't want to use all cpus in one node so i will be able to have more memory per core. ( In PBS you would do `-l nodes=16:ppn=2` for exemple)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like pe (see: qconf -sp mpi) is defaulting to $round_robin instead of $fill_up or $pe_slots.